# This compound word is a fun thing

Tags: word, no-computers

Here is an interesting compound word

> It has all the 5 vowels but used only once (no repeat of the same
>   vowel)
>
> It has 4 consecutive words that include 2 names. It starts with a name
>   and ends with a name.
>
> Of course it has 2 consecutive words; it is a compound word afterall.
>
> It has 3 consecutive words also. The last one being the name I
>   mentioned.
>
> In the middle of this word is also a bad word.

Any guesses?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> Housewarming

It has 4 consecutive words that include 2 names.

> Hou + sew + arm + ing

It starts with a name and ends with a name.

> [Hou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hou_(surname)) is a Chinese name and [Ing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ing_(surname)) is a medieval English surname.

Of course it has 2 consecutive words; it is a compound word afterall.

> House + warming

It has 3 consecutive words also. The last one being the name I mentioned.

> House + warm + ing

In the middle of this word is also a bad word.

> War

Comment: Ho and Ming are Asian Names. So Ho, Use, War and Ming!

Comment: Funnily enough, that was my first instinct but I mixed it up a bit so that I wasn't writing war so many times. Was this the word you were thinking of?